# Can't deploy the project because WeldStartService Failed to start service?

Tags: java, wildfly, java-ee-8

I use Wildfly 18 with Javaee 8, for some reason it dosen't want to deploy. I did search on internet but hopelessly didn't find any solution. Tried with different version of Wildfly but this also did not help.

**Does anyone know why this happens and what is the workaround?**

**Error is as below:**

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."acounting-web-1.0.93-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."acounting-web-1.0.93-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:108)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:913)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverInterfaces(HierarchyDiscovery.java:145)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverFromClass(HierarchyDiscovery.java:141)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverTypes(HierarchyDiscovery.java:132)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverInterfaces(HierarchyDiscovery.java:150)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverFromClass(HierarchyDiscovery.java:141)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverTypes(HierarchyDiscovery.java:113)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverFromClass(HierarchyDiscovery.java:139)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverTypes(HierarchyDiscovery.java:113)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.<init>(HierarchyDiscovery.java:94)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.<init>(HierarchyDiscovery.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.computeValue(TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.java:41)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.computeValue(TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.java:31)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotated.getTypeClosure(BackedAnnotated.java:27)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.AbstractEnhancedAnnotated.getTypeClosure(AbstractEnhancedAnnotated.java:201)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.getTypes(Beans.java:417)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.attributes.BeanAttributesFactory$BeanAttributesBuilder.<init>(BeanAttributesFactory.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.attributes.BeanAttributesFactory.forBean(BeanAttributesFactory.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.createManagedBean(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:279)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createClassBean(BeanDeployer.java:221)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

21:45:55,325 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "acounting-web-1.0.93-SNAPSHOT")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"acounting-web-1.0.93-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException"}}
21:45:55,327 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "acounting-web-1.0.93-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"acounting-web-1.0.93-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException"}}
21:45:55,354 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'acounting-web-1.0.93-SNAPSHOT#default'
21:45:55,362 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped acounting-web-1.0.93-SNAPSHOT#default.default-query-results-region cache from hibernate container
21:45:55,363 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.beans] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) HHH10005004: Stopping BeanContainer : org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl@2d32744d
21:45:55,365 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped acounting-web-1.0.93-SNAPSHOT#default.default-update-timestamps-region cache from hibernate container
21:45:55,369 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'acounting-web-1.0.93-SNAPSHOT#default'
21:45:55,885 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment acounting-web-1.0.93-SNAPSHOT (runtime-name: acounting-web-1.0.93-SNAPSHOT.war) in 557ms
[2020-04-26 09:45:55,927] Artifact acounting-web:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2020-04-26 09:45:55,927] Artifact acounting-web:war exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"acounting-web-1.0.93-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException"}}
```

Comment: Could be a library version mismatch, between the one used to compile and the one available on the server

Comment: Thanks @areus
Which library? Do you means weld library? As far as I see in the pom there isn't any weld lib.

Comment: No, any library with beans injected, or that your beans extends.